# login using next auth in vecel deployed app is rectedting to localhost (http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin)

Tags: deployment, vercel, next.js13, next-auth

I have deployed a next js app using vercel ([Link](https://issue-tracker-eight-xi.vercel.app/)) when i click on login button it is redirecting to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin .

1. I have tried updating the NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable to https://issue-tracker-eight-xi.vercel.app/ but that doesnt work.

2.I have checked the automatically expose system envirronment variables button in vercel.

3.Added current app origins too in google oauth credentials.

NOTHING WORKED FOR ME!!!

here is my git repo link [Link](https://github.com/ROHAN13498/issueTracker)